# How set list value for attribute of class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created a class `distance_neighbor` in which one of the attributes is a list of objects of class `Crime`. 
 That is the value for all attributes I get from database query result.

At first, I have set `data_Crime` list as the value for attribute `**Crime` on class `distance_neighbor`, and I used del to clear data_Crime list after used, so that the `data_Crime` list can used in the next loop.

This is my code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='Chicago_crime' user='postgres'  host='localhost' password='1234'")
cur= conn.cursor()

minDistance=float(input("Nilai minimum distance : "))
cur.execute("""SELECT id_objek1, objek1, id_objek2, objek2, distance from tb_distance1 where distance<'%f'""" %(minDistance))

class Crime:
   def __init__(self, id_jenis, jenis):
      self.id_jenis=id_jenis
      self.jenis=jenis

class distance_neighbor (Crime):
   def __init__(self, distance, **Crime):
      self.distance = distance
      self.Crime = Crime

data_Crime =[]
data_distance = []

for id_objek1, objek1, id_objek2, objek2, distance in cur.fetchall():
    data_Crime.append(Crime(id_objek1,objek1))
    data_Crime.append(Crime(id_objek2,objek2))
    data_distance.append(distance_neighbor(distance, data_Crime))
    del data_Crime[:]
```

error Message:

```
data_distance.append(distance_neighbor(distance, data_Crime))   
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I have fixed my code using below answers guys, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be closer to what you want:

```
class Crime(object):
    def __init__(self, id_jenis, jenis):
        self.id_jenis=id_jenis
        self.jenis=jenis

class DistanceNeighbor(object):
    def __init__(self, distance, crimes):
        self.distance = distance
        self.crimes = crimes


data_distance = []
for id_objek1, objek1, id_objek2, objek2, distance in cur.fetchall():
    crimes = [Crime(id_objek1,objek1), Crime(id_objek2,objek2)]
    data_distance.append(DistanceNeighbor(distance, crimes))
```

Classes in Python 2 should always inherit from `object`. By convention, class names are in CamelCase.

The inheritance of `DistanceNeighbor` from `Crime` seems unnecessary. I changed this.

Attributes to instance should be lower case, therefore I used `crimes` instead of the very confusing reuse of the class name `Crime`.

This line:

```
def __init__(self, distance, **Crime):
```

takes your list of `Crime` instance apart as separate arguments.
In your case it means the `__init__` receives:

```
distance, data_Crime[0], data_Crime[0]
```

this causes this error message:

```
TypeError: init() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

The instantiation of `Crime` is pretty short. So, instead of the two appends you can create the list of the two `Crime` instances in one line:

```
crimes = [Crime(id_objek1,objek1), Crime(id_objek2,objek2)]
```

Since this creates a new list in each loop, there is no need to delete the list content in each loop, as you did with `del data_Crime[:]`.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined your `__init__` method in `distance_neighbor` as taking arguments `(self, distance, **Crime)`. The `**` before `Crime` tells Python to pack up any keyword arguments you're passed into a dictionary named `Crime`. That's not what you're doing though. Your call is `distance_neighbor(distance, data_Crime)` where `data_Crime` is a list. You should just accept that as a normal argument in the `__init__` method:

```
class distance_neighbor (Crime):
   def __init__(self, distance, crime):
      self.distance = distance
      self.crime = crime
```

This will mostly work, but you'll still have an issue. The problem is that the loop that's creating the `distance_neighbor` objects is reusing the same list for all of them (and using `del data_Crime[:]` to clear the values in between). If you are keeping a reference to the same list in the objects, they'll all end up with references to that same list (which will be empty) at the end of the loop.

Instead, you should create a new list for each iteration of your loop:

```
for id_objek1, objek1, id_objek2, objek2, distance in cur.fetchall():
    data_Crime = [Crime(id_objek1,objek1), Crime(id_objek2,objek2)]
    data_distance.append(distance_neighbor(distance, data_Crime))
```

This will work, but there are still more things that you probably want to improve in your code. To start with, `distance_neighbor` is defined as inheriting from `Crime`, but that doesn't seem appropiate since it *contains* instance of `Crime`, rather than being one itself. It should probably inherit from `object` (or nothing if you're in Python 3 where `object` is the default base). You may also want to change your class and variable names to match Python convention: `CamelCase` for class names and `lower_case_with_underscores` for functions, variables and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, distance, **Crime):
```

`**Crime` is a keyword argument, and expects named arguments. You don't need that, remove the asterisks.

Also, rename the argument, it's very confusing that it has the same name as the class:

```
class distance_neighbor(Crime):
   def __init__(self, distance, c):
      self.distance = distance
      self.Crime = c
```